# 3 Tables into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in my database, looking something like this:

**Main table**

| Team ID | Name ID |
| --- | --- |
| Set ID 1 | Name ID 1 |
| Set ID 1 | Name ID 2 |
| Set ID 1 | Name ID 3 |
| Set ID 2 | Name ID 1 |
| Set ID 2 | Name ID 2 |

**Name Table**

| Name ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Name ID 1 | (insert random name) |
| Name ID 2 | (insert more gibberish) |

**Team Table**

| Team ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Team ID 1 | (insert random set name) |
| Team ID 2 | (insert some more gibberish) |

Basically I'm trying to replace the main table with the names instead of the Ids, something like this:

| Team | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Avengers | Captain America |
| Avengers | Spiderman |
| Avengers | Hawkeye |
| Sinister 6 | Electro |
| Sinister 6 | Mysterio |

I'm using the following code but doesn't seem to want to work

```
select name.name, team.name
from main_table main
inner join team_table team
on main.team_id = team.team_id
inner join name_table name
on main.name_id = name.name_id
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: what are you selecting in main_table?

Comment: nothing, actually. the only thing in the main tables are the IDs, so I wanted to get the corresponding names from the other tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query works just fine.
The order has to be defined as resulsets are unsorted by nature

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Main_table (
>   `Team ID` INTEGER,
>   `Name ID` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Main_table
>   (`Team ID`, `Name ID`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1'),
>   ('1', '2'),
>   ('1', '3'),
>   ('2', '1'),
>   ('2', '2');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Name_Table (
>   `Name ID` INTEGER,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Name_Table
>   (`Name ID`, `Name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'name1'),
>   ('2', 'name2'),
>   ('3', 'name3'),
>   ('4', 'name4');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Team_Table (
>   `Team ID` INTEGER,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Team_Table
>   (`Team ID`, `Name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'team1'),
>   ('2', 'team2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t.Name,n.Name 
> FROM Main_table m INNER JOIN Name_Table n ON n.`Name ID` = m.`Name ID` INNER JOIN Team_Table t ON t.`Team ID` = m.`Team ID`
> ORDER BY t.name,n.Name
> ```
>
> ```
> Name  | Name 
> :---- | :----
> team1 | name1
> team1 | name2
> team1 | name3
> team2 | name1
> team2 | name2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26590baa6b013ed14d6d12cf4c9fa348)*